# Hide product on add to cart click woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using *woocommerce addons* to get users to upload **pdfs** on the product. After they have clicked '**add to cart**', and submitted a pdf, I would like to hide the '*file upload*' input and the product.

I am looking at `document.getElementsByClassName` and have some kind of event listener but not sure how to complete the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(event) { 
    jQuery('.single-product').toggle('hide'); }); 

    });
```

Comment: your code,your errors?

Comment: I am not even sure how to start really, was looking for suggestions...

Comment: Post at least a link to the website if you don't have any knowledge.

Comment: suggestion 1 learn javascript ,suggestion 2. hire someone to do it for you

Comment: loving the sarcasm, @madalin ivascu, but that does not help me. I have tried this the jquery way but this does not work: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(event) {        
             jQuery('.single-product').toggle('hide');
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try using hide() function:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('.single_add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(event) { 
       event.preventDefault();
     jQuery('.single-product').hide(); //or jQuery(this).parent('.single-product').hide();
      jQuery(this).hide();
    }); 
    });
```

Comment: Ok I will give this a go and let you know what it comes out with. My suspicion is that I will have to enque the script on the page...many thanks